# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot' while forecasting

Tags: python, numpy, plot, multidimensional-array, forecasting

I'm trying to forecast with SARIMA model but it keeps showing

```
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'plot'
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

```
ax = monthly_mean['2016':].plot(label='observed')
predictions.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, label='One-step ahead Forecast', alpha=.7)

ax.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 0],
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 1], color='k', alpha=.2)

ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('CO2 Levels')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to plot a dataframe, not a numpy array.

Comment: Apparently `predictions.predicted_mean` is an array.  Array can be passed as an argument to `plt.plot`.  It does not have a `plot` method.  What made you think that was possible?